# QuotaExceededError using Ionic Storage with a few strings

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm having this issue with Ionic Storage, this is the complete stack trace:

```
core.es5.js:1084 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): QuotaExceededError: 
at c (polyfills.js:3)
at c (polyfills.js:3)
at polyfills.js:3
at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:4140)
at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
at r.runTask (polyfills.js:3)
at o (polyfills.js:3)
at IDBTransaction.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
```

I'm using the settigs servis as recommended in Ionic super template.

this is happening testing on browser (Chrome)

Comment: For Chrome try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52635590/7752468

Answer (score 39, accepted):

By chance, tonight I discovered that the hard disk of my windows PC was almost full, which was generating problems of virtual memory, and specifically in chrome problems with the local storage

Comment: I have the same problem on Mac if I have less than 1Go free on my hard disk.

Comment: same issue on ubuntu 14.04. Guess it affects every os

Comment: same on the Windows 10 (900 MB) :p

Comment: It didn't work for me. I use ionic-native-storage to solve this problem.

Comment: correct answer.. local storage set value end with error... when i delete some file app works fine...

Comment: my laptop was running out of space too. :/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and discovered that my hard disk running short of space. Cleared the memory and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this:

```
IonicStorageModule.forRoot({
  name: ‘__mydb’,
  driverOrder: [‘sqlite’, ‘websql’, ‘indexeddb’]
})
```