# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): QuotaExceededError Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, local-storage, ionic3

I am creating an app with ionic 3. I am saving a string in ionic storage. I was working fine but suddenly I am getting this error.

[image]

Home.ts (This is where I am setting my string)

```
          this.storage.set("123", JSON.stringify(data))
          .then(() => {
             console.log("Saved")
          })
```

My string:

`{"ImagePath":"Attachment/ProfileThumbnail/20180412134416Picture.jpg","name":"Sal man Ullah Khan","userId":238}`

Comment: are you using localstorage or ionic-storage? localstorage doesnt use promises

Comment: My bad I am using  ionic-storage.

Comment: does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45065299/quotaexceedederror-using-ionic-storage-with-a-few-strings help?

Comment: Nope. I have 5gb of free space in my internal storage.

Comment: is this in device or browser? also are you using any specific storage underneath like sqlite?

Comment: either way it might be an indication that it is full or it maxed how much you can store

Comment: Yeah I can understand that too. I tried clearing storage and data from the devices but still no luck.

Comment: I'm also getting this, on mobile chrome, also tried clearing the storage, no luck. Did you find a solution?

Comment: in my case it was the quota being reduced by Chrome being rather aggressive. Now there's a method to get the available quota: navigator.storage.estimate().then(function(estimate) {
      console.log((estimate.usage / estimate.quota).toFixed(2));})

Answer (score 0):

Just clear the storage of your App in the browser.

**Chrome**:
Go to DevTools. Press F12, Application tab then Clear storage.